# I want to convert DATEADD("d",- (DAY(GETDATE())) + 1,GETDATE()) to YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, derived-column

The expresssion

```
DATEADD("d",- (DAY(GETDATE())) + 1,GETDATE())
```

is correct and its giving me 
2/1/2019 3:45:02 PM

But i want my answer to be as `2019-02-01` in SSIS

PLease help me

Comment: the only way to change the date format to that is to make it a string

Comment: Also, you should save formatting for the presentation layer

Comment: Where do you want your output to look this way?  The data is a timestamp -- it has no format.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, SSIS is a bit of a pain when it comes to handling dates. Basically, you have to double cast it...

```
(DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)DATEADD("d",- (DAY(GETDATE())) + 1,GETDATE())
```

Note: The evaluated value is `2/1/2019 12:00:00 AM`. But, when you click OK on the Expression Builder, you will see the value displayed as `2/1/2019`.

**Edit** To my knowledge, it is not possible to change the date format, even with converting it to string and then back to date. I wouldn't consider this a problem - leave the internal date format alone so that the back-end can handle it. The date format should only really be of any concern for display purposes, which can be manipulated during the SQL SELECT phase.

Is there a reason that you require the date format to be changed for back-end processing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the value `2019-02-01` (format `yyyy-MM-dd`) then you should convert the value to a string and use the following expression:

```
LEFT((DT_WSTR,50)DATEADD("d",- (DAY(GETDATE())) + 1,GETDATE()) ,10)
```

*Output*

> 2019-02-01

Based on the [Cast (SSIS Expression) official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017):

> When a string is cast to a DT_DATE, or vice versa, the locale of the transformation is used. However, the date is in the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD, regardless of whether the locale preference uses the ISO format.

If you need the returned value of type `DT_Date` then just add a CAST operation:

```
(DT_DATE)LEFT((DT_WSTR,50)DATEADD("d",- (DAY(GETDATE())) + 1,GETDATE()) ,10)
```

*Note that in Date data type there is no formatting, values are not stored in the same way they are visualized.*

*Output*

> 2/1/2019 12:00:00 AM

Which is equivalent to

> 2/1/2019 00:00:00